# Larger MessageBox.Show() font

Tags: c#, messagebox

first post on here.

I am trying to make a "better" notepad, and I'd like to keep it as similar as possible.

When you close notepad without saving, you will get a popup with slightly bigger and blue text. Could you do this without a custom message box?

Notepad screenshot:
[image: Notepad screenshot]

Comment: Your screenshot looks like it was made with a [TaskDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.taskdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), which will also allow you to customize the buttons (you can't make Save/Don't Save buttons with MessageBox). Note that you'll need .NET 5+ for that. (Or a third party library, or plain old Windows API.)

Comment: How about Notepad++? 

Comment: ^^i think that's exactly what i want. thanks

Comment: ^i find notepad++ slow and a bit confusing

Comment: If you find Notepad++ slow, than I'm very exicted to see your version and how it performs on larger files. 